# Execute echo inside of an echo

Tags: php, switch-statement, echo

I´ve this code:

```
 echo '<div style="background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-image:url(http://render-api-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/static-
 render/eu/' . $newString.');">

 switch ($rasse) {
case "11":
    echo "Tauren";
    break;
case "12":
    echo "Troll!";
    break;
default:
    echo "No Character.";
}
```

The problem is that I´ve an echo inside of an echo so the "switch-statement" doesn´t get executed. How do I handle thi?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Looks more like to me that he has a Quoting issue  it ends with a double quote and there is no double quote

Comment: $rasse = $race? also @Forbs is right close your echo string `'<div></div>';`

Comment: Might just need to turn on errors or look in log.  Probably syntax error on first echo / missing closing quote.

Comment: The problem is that I´ve echo commands in the switch statement, too and now the switch doesn´t get executed. It is because I already echo out the div style. My question is now, is their any possibility to get that code working? It´s just a part of the code, of course i closed the div.

Comment: just add a single quote and a semicolon at the end of the first echo `';`

Comment: @splash58 That won't work. You can't put statements in the arguments to `echo`, only expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write `';` after `echo '<div style="background-size: 100%;...`, and that's causing problems (and also the reason why the code isn't running as desired):

```
echo '<div style="background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;  
                  background-image:url(http://render-api-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/eu/' . $newString.');">';
switch ($rasse) {
    case "11":
        echo "Tauren";
    break;
    case "12":
        echo "Troll!";
    break;
    default:
        echo "No Character.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i also get a white page.

Comment: @Mr.Curser - What do you mean?

Comment: The code isn´t working as expected. I just get a white page now.

Comment: @Mr.Curser Do you see any error message? I tried to run this code (and defined `$newString = 'text'; $rasse = "12";` since I don't know the original variables) and it worked, so please give me an information - what was wrong?